# Haskell Pipes: Understanding the logic of the "for equality"

Tags: haskell, pipe

At the [Pipes tutorial](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.7/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html), it says that this:

```
 -- s :: Monad m =>      Producer a m ()  -- i.e. 'P.stdinLn'
 -- f :: Monad m => a -> Producer b m ()  -- i.e. 'duplicate'
 -- g :: Monad m => b -> Producer c m ()  -- i.e. '(lift . putStrLn)'    
 for (for s f) g = for s (\x -> for (f x) g)
```

plus this:

```
 (~>) :: Monad m
      => (a -> Producer b m ())
      -> (b -> Producer c m ())
      -> (a -> Producer c m ())
 (f ~> g) x = for (f x) g
```

equals this:

```
 f :: Monad m => a -> Producer b m ()
 g :: Monad m => b -> Producer c m ()
 h :: Monad m => c -> Producer d m ()
 (f ~> g) ~> h = f ~> (g ~> h)
```

which makes no sense to me. Could someone please clarify?

Comment: Expand the expression `(f ~> g) ~> h = f ~> (g ~> h)` using the definition of `~>`. The result is exactly the first theorem, but slightly more specific: `all y . for (for (f y) g) h = for (f y) (\x -> for (g x) h)`.

Comment: Perhaps it's easier to read if the definition of `~>` is rewritten as `(~>) = \f g x -> for (f x) g` ? I can see how using infix and postfix notation together can cause confusion.

Comment: @chi I'm confused because the `x` has disappeared. Not experienced in these derivations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking hints from the comments, I've figured it out. Thanks everyone.

First:

```
  (f ~> g) x =       for (f x) g
  (f ~> g)   = \x -> for (f x) g
  (~>) f g   = \x -> for (f x) g
```

Hence:

```
        for (for s f) g, s = e x
= \x -> for (for (e x) f) g
= \x -> for ((e ~> f) x) g
= (e ~> f) ~> g
```

and

```
        for s     (\x -> for (f x) g), s = e x
= \x -> for (e x) (\x -> for (f x) g)
= \x -> for (e x) (f ~> g)
= e ~> (f ~> g)
```